# Writing code for nim game but condition for empty list not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

def game():

```
print("Welcome to Nim!")
nim_list_1 = ['*', '*', '*']
nim_list_2 = ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
nim_list_3 = ['*', '*', '*', '*','*', '*', '*']
player = 1
pile_num = [1,2,3]



print("Pile 1:", *nim_list_1)
print("Pile 2:", *nim_list_2)
print("Pile 3:", *nim_list_3)       


while (nim_list_1 and nim_list_2) or nim_list_3 is not None:
       # Catches IndexError if we try to pop from empty list
    try:
        count = 0 
        while count != pick and pile is not None:
            count += 1
            pile.pop()

    except IndexError:
        print("Can't remove sticks from empty pile")
```

The problem I am facing is: the while loop is still executing even when the list is empty. I want the function to display the winner as soon as the all the lists become empty? Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your stated goal "to display the winner as soon as the all the lists become **empty**", the test `nim_list_3 is not None` is completely wrong!

An empty list is "falsy", but that doesn't mean it's `None`!  So, just testing

```
while (nim_list_1 and nim_list_2) or nim_list_3:
```

would accomplish (something closer to) your stated goal -- exiting when list 3 is empty and either list 1 is empty or list 2 is.  That's not the same as "all the lists become empty" but it's closer than that check against `None`!-)

To actually state "exit only when all lists are empty", it should be:

```
while nim_list_1 or nim_list_2 or nim_list_3:
```

Of course, since you show us nothing about how the lists are updated, it's hard to guess whether you actually mean what you say ("all lists become empty") or what you code (where the three lists are treated differently).

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear in the previous code I had stated, I have edited my code to display how the lists are being updated.

Comment: @dev_prabh, still very confusing -- the body of the `while` uses a `pile` variable that's never defined anywhere (and a `pick` one ditto).  Anyway, as the only list operation is a `.pop()`, I confirm that may make a list empty, but it can never, ever, magically turn it into a `None`!-)